# IllegalStateException: Could not load specified mime type mapping file [org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types]

Tags: java, spring

I am using Springframework's **JavaMailSenderImpl** class to send email from my Java program and it works fine in my local but in the production environment I am getting below exception intermittently

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource 
                                  [org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types] 
                                   cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I researched and checked the stack trace and found out this exception is being thrown from `org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap` class's createFileTypeMap method : [Source Code of ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/mail/javamail/ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java)

Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load specified MIME type mapping file: class path resource [org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.getFileTypeMap(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:122) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.afterPropertiesSet(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:106) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.getDefaultFileTypeMap(MimeMessageHelper.java:455) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.<init>(MimeMessageHelper.java:292) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.<init>(MimeMessageHelper.java:247) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.<init>(MimeMessageHelper.java:226) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/mail/javamail/mime.types] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.createFileTypeMap(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:145) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.getFileTypeMap(ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap.java:119) ~[spring-context-support-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
2018-09-07T10:00:20.463+0000 INFO  : logg
```

Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue or just point me to the right direction to proceed.

Comment: Do you have 'spring-context-support' dependency in your maven/gradle file

Comment: @yogi Yes it's present, could you please tell me the role of this dependency with this problem.

Comment: Class which you have mentioned is present in spring-context-support jar.So you need dependency to add this jar into runtime libs.